# Git rebase on tags and not individual commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit, git-tag

I have a project where my development branch is 2 tagged releases ahead of my stable branch but I want to remove the first tagged set of changes (which is a series of functionality I no longer want) but apply the most recent tagged changes (second tag) onto the stable tag.

For example:

Commits:

```
[tag] 3.0 - 
sdaf213 Some Commit of the tag 3
sdaas34 Some other commit in this tag
[tag] 2.0 -
wert78 Some commit of tag 2
werg99 Another commit of tag 2
werh55 And another of tag 2
[tag] 1.0 (Stable) -
pry77 Commits of tag 1
...older commits
```

Is there a way to git rebase on tags and not commits such that I can rebase all the commits of [tag] 3.0 on top of [tag] 1.0 but exclude everything from [tag] 2.0?

Comment: tags _are_ (identifiers for) commits. You can almost always use a tag instead of an SHA

Answer (score 4):

You can do it simply by:

```
git rebase --onto 1.0 2.0 BRANCH
```

where BRANCH is the name of your branch you want to apply the rebase to.

This will use 1.0 tag as the parent and then replay the commits of the 3.0 tag in order:

```
sdaf213 Some Commit of the tag 3
sdaas34 Some other commit in this tag
1.0 (Stable) -
pry77 Commits of tag 1
...older commits
```

As you can see the 3.0 tag will not be reapplied to the end of your history. You will have to create a new one, although this makes sense since the history has changed and you may want to make this 2.1 or 3.1 to fit your needs.

Additionally, you could use this over a series of tags. For example if you were now on [tag] 4.0 and wanted to get rid of [tag] 2.0 and 3.0:

```
git rebase --onto 1.0 3.0 BRANCH
```